# Zeroing a Vernier force probe

Tags: arduino-uno, documentation

For a class assignment I have been tasked with zeroing a Vernier force probe by typing a command into the serial monitor. I am having trouble writing the code for this algorithim. I was hoping to give the monitor the command and have it save the analogread as a variable which I can later subtract from future reads. Does anyone know if I can save the analogread value without it being updated in a loop? If, so how?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is what you mean, but:

```
const int FP = 0;  // force probe analog pin
const int OFFSET = 10; // your deadband depending on your sensors consistency too
int init_read = 0;  // initial read
int curr_read = 0;  // this will be constantly updated till zeroing is done

void setup(){
  Serial.begin(9600);
  //the rest of your setup()
}

void loop(){
  if (Serial.available() && (Serial.read() == 'z')){  // if you sent anything with the monitor and if 'z' is present   
    init_read = analogRead(FP); // initial read from sensor before 'zeroing' begins 
    while (abs(curr_read - init_read) < OFFSET){ // here you indicate the condition that would mean the probe has been zeroed
      // make your adjustments or whatever
      curr_read = analogRead(FP);  // take a new reading and check in the next iteration
    }
    Serial.print("Zeroing is done.");
  }
}
```

`z` is the command you send from the serial monitor to begin zeroing.

Comment: There is usually some jitter in analogRead, so you might want to compare for "almost the same".

Comment: Right...will edit...

Comment: The main issue i am having is saving an analog read value. This seems to be an issue because the analogread value keeps refreshing. Essentially what i want to do is save an inital analogread value as "x" and then have the proceeding values be realreading-x=reading

Comment: @JaimeTorres If you place your variable 'x' in setup() like I did, it wont be updated. Do you understand the code above?